# Python one-time result ? RTIMU Lib

Tags: python

I want to get a one-time result, I don't want to loop. Is there any replacement for IMURead ()? does it work only in a loop?

```
import RTIMU
import os.path
import time
import math
sys.path.append('.')

class compass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.SETTINGS_FILE = "RTIMULib"
        s = RTIMU.Settings(self.SETTINGS_FILE)
        self.imu = RTIMU.RTIMU(s)

    def get_heading(self):

        self.imu.IMUInit()

        self.imu.setSlerpPower(0.06)
        self.imu.setAccelEnable(True)
        self.imu.setCompassEnable(True)

        poll_interval = self.imu.IMUGetPollInterval()

        while True:
            if self.imu.IMURead():
                data = self.imu.getIMUData()
                magX = data["compass"][0]
                magY = data["compass"][1]
                magZ = data["compass"][2]
```

Answer (score 1):

2 options :

using break :

```
    while True:
        if self.imu.IMURead():
            data = self.imu.getIMUData()
            magX = data["compass"][0]
            magY = data["compass"][1]
            magZ = data["compass"][2]
            break
```

using while :

```
    while not self.imu.IMURead():
        pass

    data = self.imu.getIMUData()
    magX = data["compass"][0]
    magY = data["compass"][1]
    magZ = data["compass"][2]
```